# Calcular Comisiones

Tags: python, django, django-models

Necesito calcular la comisión que debe tener un doctor por los exámenes de laboratorio que envía a sus paciente. Es decir el laboratorio le paga por cada orden enviada.

Aquí tengo la tabla de parametrizacion de comisiones:

```
class Comisiones(models.Model):
  precio_inicial = models.IntegerField()
  precio_final = models.IntegerField()
  porcentaje_comision = models.IntegerField()
  doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctores, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

  def full_name(self):
        return u'{} []'.format(self.precio_inicial, self.precio_final, self.porcentaje_comision)
```

Aquí tengo la tabla donde se registra la orden:

```
class OrdenPaciente(models.Model):
   paciente =  models.ForeignKey(Pacientes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctores, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   estado_paciente = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   status = models.BooleanField(default=True)
   fecha_solicitud = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
   dias = models.CharField(max_length=3)
   precio = models.IntegerField()
```

Aquí la tabla donde se registra la Comisiones

```
class ComisionesCalculo(models.Model):
   orden = models.ForeignKey(OrdenPaciente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   comision = models.ForeignKey(Comisiones, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   calculo = models.DecimalField(default=0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)

   def full_name(self):
        return u'{} []'.format(self.orden, self.comision, self.calculo)
```

Alguien me ayuda como podría calcular la comisione en base al precio y al porcentaje de comisión parametrizado en el modelo Comisiones

Comment: te recomiendo mejorar la indentación de tú codigo. :)

Comment: alli solo tienes el modelo , el calculo lo debes hacer en las vistas(view)

Comment: Correcto, como podría empezar el calculo en las vistas. Soy relativamente nuevo en Python

Comment: @RobertoFeijoo fuera de tu problema actual te recomienda primero entender y probar el excelente tutorial que provee django.

Comment: La fórmula matemática de cómo se haría el cálculo seria de mucha ayuda, tu explicación no me queda del todo clara

Comment: Esta es la formula matematica: ((orden.precio)*(comision.porcentaje_comision))/100. Primero obtengo cuanto es la comision con: comision = Comisiones.objects.get(doctor_id=orden.doctor_id,precio_final__gte=orden.precio,precio_inicial__lte=orden.precio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Así fue como lo resolví

```
 def calcular_comisiones(id):
   orden = OrdenPaciente.objects.get(id=id)
   try:
       comision = Comisiones.objects.get(doctor_id=orden.doctor_id,precio_final__gte=orden.precio,precio_inicial__lte=orden.precio)
       calculo = ((orden.precio)*(comision.porcentaje_comision))/100
       comcal = ComisionesCalculo()
       comcal.ordenid_id = id
       comcal.comision_id = comision.id
       comcal.calculo = calculo
       comcal.paciente_id = orden.paciente_id
       comcal.doctor_id = orden.doctor_id
       comcal.save()

  except Comisiones.DoesNotExist:
       pass
  return HttpResponse(True)
```